# Which one to use for boosting bq or q.alt

Tags: solr

As the title says which one I need to use for boosting in solr. whether its q.alt or bq. I tried the boosting in both however I'm not clear on how the boosting is working. Because in q.alt I got the correct results when I specified boosting value as 1000 at the same time I got the same results in bq with the boosting value as 2

Can someone help me to get the best practices for boosting?

My SOLR version is 3.5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends upon what are you trying to boost.

Use [qf (query fields)](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DisMaxQParserPlugin#qf_.28Query_Fields.29) - to boost the individual search fields which have different weightage.

for e.g. For a document title has a higher weightage then description then you would use `title^2 description^1`

`q.alt` is just an alternate query factor in case on `q` is specified.

Use [bq](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DisMaxQParserPlugin#bq_.28Boost_Query.29) and [bf](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DisMaxQParserPlugin#bf_.28Boost_Functions.29) for boosting certain matches, ranges or when the need to apply some functions on them. These usually are the extar boost and not the part of the search boost.

for e.g. for latest documents you would boost by date, or Price range or you want to boost on sum of fields etc ...

Answer (score 2):

use `qf` parameter for boosting

[Dismax Query Parser Wiki](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DisMaxQParserPlugin)